# How to write in arabic in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, utf-8

I have an application that reads a file then a user updates the file with different language and saves it. But whenever anyone changes the language and saves the txt file change the  letters into symbols ??? I think i have to save it as utf-8 formatted. Any idea?
The next part of code where i get the data from a jtable and save it to a file when user click at save button.
Note: there is nothing wrong with the code. The problem is that the file has to be saved as utf-8.

```
if(buttonPressed.equals(save)){

         File myFile = new File("youFile.srt");

            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myFile)) {   

            for (int i =0 ; i< cModel.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
               sData.add(cModel.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
               eData.add(cModel.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
               tData.add(cModel.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
               writer.println(i+1 + "\n");
               writer.println(sData.get(i)+" --> " + eData.get(i));
               writer.println(tData.get(i));
               writer.println("\n");
            }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ioEx){
               ioEx.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure the culprit isn't the reading ? (You need to read with the good encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrintWriter need to be clubbed with OutputStreamWriter because it offers constructors to provide the file format. Here is what you can do:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a FileWriter. It is better to create a FileOutputStream and then use OutputStreamWriter to write the output. OutputStreamWriter allows you to specify the encoding.

```
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("youFile.srt"), "UTF-8"));
try {
    writer.write(aString);
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```